# Is this Complex conjugate integration and complex integration same?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

If x(t) is a complex energy signal, are $$\int_{-^\infty}^{+^\infty}x^{*}(t).e^{j.2\pi.f.t}dt $$ and $$ \int_{-^\infty}^{+^\infty}x(t).e^{j.2\pi.f.t}dt$$ both same. In the given pdf [link](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~damours/courses/ELG_3175/Lec4.pdf) it is given as equal. It will be helpful for me to see the proof of this.

Comment: The link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DepeHb : I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equal.  To see this, just pick any real $x(t)$ which gives a convergent non-zero integral, and then consider $i x(t)$ (sorry, but I can't bring myself to use $j$ for $\sqrt{-1}$).

In the PDF to which you link, *real* functions $x(t)$ are explicitly being considered when that equality is written down, in which case it's trivial.